# coldfusion ajax return unstyled content with jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, coldfusion

I am following [Ray Camdens post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/3/20/Simple-example-of-a-Form-post-to-ColdFusion-with-jQuery) on ajax calls in coldfusion. I have the whole page wrapped with jquerymobile and themeroller. If I put the content on the main page, its styled properly, but if I use ajax to return the content, its unstyled.

[image: Unstyled]

I have tried including jquery and jquerymobile scripts in the ajax page, but then I end up getting weird loops and double submit buttons. In firebug I can see that it loads the js files in the ajax return. I also loose my focus on the submit button which is a big deal in this particular app.

[image: Styled and odd]

Is there a way to only have the jquery a jquery mobile js files linked in the main page and then have the styling refresh after the ajax content is loaded? or will i run into a FOUC?

Comment: Fixed.

used `$("#result").html(data).trigger("create");` as mentioned in the comments on [this page](http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2011/3/15/jQuery-Mobile-styling-loaded-content)

Comment: Please add your comment as answer & select as correct answer, it will help others.

Comment: I cant for the first 8 days until i have 100 cred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. used $("#result").html(data).trigger("create"); as mentioned in the comments on [this page](http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2011/3/15/jQuery-Mobile-styling-loaded-content)